# ASP.Net MVC 1.0 Web Hosting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I am developing a website using ASP.Net MVC 1.0. Can i host that website on a server having ASP.Net 2.0? Because my hosting provider supports only ASP.Net 2.0. Does anyone know how to host a website developed using ASP.Net MVC 1.0 in a web server supports ASP.Net 2.0

Comment: Isn't ASP.NET MVC framework dependent on 3.5?  Technically you can ship the DLLs to the bin to see if what they have will work with what you have as the MVC is built on standard webforms framework.  It will work or it won't...but I think it won't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can run asp.net mvc without 3.5. I know you can run MVC on a iis 6 server(with 3.5 installed) but that already required extra work.

As people have stated it you should switch to new hosting company or demand your hosting company to upgrade to 3.5. Like come on it gets built on top of 3.5 and should not be much work to for them to have 3.5 installed.

If your hosting company is too lazy to keep up with the newest stuff(4.0 will be out probably in a couple months) then why stick with them where there are so many hosting companies that support 3.5?

I recommend [Reliable hosting](http://payments.reliablesite.net/aff.php?aff=026). They are very cheap, give a free mssql database(others charge $10/month extra) and keep up with the newest technologies.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked with [DiscountASP](http://www.discountasp.net/) and have had good luck with them.

Comment: +1 for DiscountASP. Great company. i'm on my third ASP.NET site with them. But i don't think MVC will run with only .Net 2.0. Though it will run with IIS 6.

Comment: DiscountASP.Net does offer .Net 3.5, and gives you the option of running under either Windows 2003 with IIS 6 or Windows 2008 with IIS 7.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC requires at least .NET 3.5 as i know but you can (devil smile)

read this:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DeployingASPNETMVCOnASPNET20.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I have used the webhost4life, it is good based on my experience.

Asp.Net mvc also supports bin deployment, meaning that you can compile all the mvc assembly and deploy it into your bin directory. You may consider this solution if your hosting company doesn't have this in GAC.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using webhost4life since November 2009 and it's been great.  That is until they recently switched me over to their "new" platform.  My site broke and has been down for almost two weeks now.  I've spent numerous attempts to work with their new support team to resolve the issue, but they are complete morons.  I suggest everyone steer clear of them until they can get their act together.  Hopefully they don't lose all their customers first.

So now I'm shopping for a new hosting company.